# can I change text of legend in ggplot2? (not the legend title but test associated with symbols)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot

```
p <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl)
p + labs(colour = "Cylinders")
```

here, I get a picture with legend "Cylinders", and values 2,4,6,8,10. Can I change those values to "two", "four"...etc without going back to the dataset to change the names?

Thank you

Comment: @Didzis Thanks, damn, I could not find that searching originaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl) +
  labs(colour = "Cylinders") + 
  scale_colour_gradient(breaks = 4:8, 
                        labels = c("four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"))
```

[image]

Comment: great, Thanks..I also used the hybrid way as explained in another thread